# Wordpress one recent post from some categories

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've made some code to display one post (title with url, attachment-thumb, time and category name) from each 20 categories on my Wordpress website. Now my database grew up to > 100Mb and that code makes about 100 queries  to database. So I want to make one query to get the task.

I want to get title, url, date-time, attachment(thumb) and a category name with url for every post from selected categories. The best I've done is:

```
SELECT name, post_title, post_date_gmt, id FROM wp_posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
AND p.post_type = 'post'
AND t.term_id IN (2171, 2611, 2600) GROUP BY t.term_id HAVING MAX(ID)
```

But it works no good. It shows not recent posts but some other. Please, help to make a goal.
Sorry for bad English.

Comment: You could do the same with a [custom wordpress query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) for specific categories, which would entail the same MySQL query you're attempting to do.

Comment: sure, but I can't make a proper query

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET - although I should point out that this is perhaps the single most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag.